# Creating Jasper Report from complex object

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have to create a Jasper report from a complex object which has some following fields,

```
1. 4-5 string fields
2. List<outer object> where outer object consists of some string fields and a list of  
  inner objects. Here inner object also has some integer fields.
```

Now, in the required jasper report, I have to display horizontal bar graphs(3 bars) for every member of the list of inner objects for every outer object. Let say I have a list of 3 outer objects where each outer object has a list of 3 inner objects. I have to create 3 X 3 bar graphs and display them in the tabular structure.

outerObject1.getName()

Column1                              Column2

innerObject1.getName()                bar graph

innerObject2.getName()                bar graph

innerObject3.getName()                bar graph

outerObject2.getName()

innerObject1.getName()      bar graph

and  so on....

I understand that there are few ways of doing it,

1. creating a customized JRDataSource class
2. creating multiple  sub reports and integrate them to get a main report

I am using iReport for creating jrxml file.

Can somebody help me in creating tabular structure from such a complex object??

Answer (score 0):

You can write like that

in the field take one field

and change your name like that

Suppose you have one class `Order.java` it has one account reference  account  has one customer object customer has a Name of customer .

**So step is :**

```
account.customer.firstname
```

define in field of jasper reports.